# Dropbox server integration php library

Tags: php, api, integration, dropbox

I need a php/js based webapp that syncs files between it's server and it's dropbox app folder 
It only needs to be a one way sync (from dropbox to the server) Any recommended libraries/tutorials/endpoints to do this?
[ same q dif platform [https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/I-need-a-php-js-based-webapp-that-syncs-files-between-it-s/td-p/419421]](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/I-need-a-php-js-based-webapp-that-syncs-files-between-it-s/td-p/419421)

[edit] to further the quality of my question - I hope this helps:

Q: describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

A: the problem is im not sure what mechanism to use to determine changes to dropbox app folder, maybe webhooks?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._ - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Dropbox already recommend some PHP and JavaScript client libraries themselves though, which might help to get you started. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/communitysdks

Comment: An alternative implementation you could use though is to install Dropbox's own client on your server, so it handles the syncing to dropbox for you. All you'd have to do then is implement a user interface so that users of your server / application can see the files in the synced Dropbox folder on the server and add/remove files from it etc. And there are already ready-made web-based file management programs which you could point at that folder and configure, so you probably don't need to write much code yourself, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Endpoints to use:

- Initial sync: download to zip (then extract)
- Thereafter syncs:

  - Check for changes trigger: Use a webhook
  - Check for changes: Use "if (strtotime($entry["server_modified"]) > strtotime("-1 minutes"))"